# Delphi ADO command with one row result

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

I want to send this query to a MS-SQL server using Delphi XE2:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   InstrumentServer.sys.tables WHERE  NAME = 'f_SensData') 
   PRINT 'TRUE'
ELSE
    PRINT 'FALSE'
```

The query returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on if the table `f_SensData` exist in the `InstrumentServer` database.

How can I implement (execute) and get the result using ADO and Delphi XE2? I do understand that I could use the ADO. CommandType and have tested a huge number of variants without success.

Comment: That query returns zero rows.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be better to use something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM InstrumentServer.sys.tables WHERE NAME = 'f_SensData') 
  SELECT cast(1 as bit) as Result
ELSE
  SELECT cast(0 as bit) as Result
```

This would return a one row one field boolean value instead of using `print` to return information that is not returned as part of a dataset.